# Android location update on location change

Tags: android

How to check whether the location update is triggered by gps provider or cellular network ?
for the code:

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
}
```

Comment: `location.getProvider()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

    // it Returns the name of the provider that generated this fix.
String locationProvider = location.getProvider()

   }
```